# discord.py - FFmpegPCMAudio using a lot of CPU

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

I made a Discord bot using the discord.py library which aims at playing a web radio in several voice channels. Basically it's the same audio stream for every channel.

What I'm doing right now is:

```
voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(stream_url))
```

However every FFmpegPCMAudio uses about 10% of my CPU and there's one for each vc so eventually my bot crashed a lot when playing in 10 channels (which isn't a lot).

Since it's the same stream, I tried the following:

```
player = FFmpegPCMAudio(stream_url)
for voice_channel in vcs:
    voice_channel.play(player)
```

But the sound was stuttering a lot (maybe it was playing the sound a bit to each sequentially like the way threading works)

Can you think of any other way I could reduce the load on the CPU since it is the same audio stream playing? Either a discord.py trick or a FFmpeg trick maybe, like manually running one FFmpeg and using it for each channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing from `FFmpegPCMAudio` to `FFmpegOpusAudio` seems to be a solution since it highly reduced the CPU usage. Probably not the best solution so I'm still waiting to see if there exist some way to have only one FFmpeg audio source.

Comment: Same here, thanks! FFmpegOpusAudio reduced usage by 30%

Comment: Yeah, from [FFmpegOpusAudio](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#ffmpegopusaudio)  "rather than producing PCM packets like FFmpegPCMAudio does that need to be encoded to Opus, this class produces Opus packets, **skipping the encoding step** done by the library."